# How to get values from a JSON object array using JQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I've been able to get data from a JSON object using the JQUERY .each(), but I can't seem to figure out how to target the array of urls I want to insert into the page as links.

Here's the getJson function

```
function getDetails(itemName) {
    $.getJSON("getDetails.json", function (data) {

        $("#description").empty();

        $.each(data, function () {
            if (this["id"] === itemName) {
                $("#description").append("<p>Description: " + this["description"] + "</p>");
                $("#description").append("<p>Price: " + this["price"] + "</p>");
                $("#description").append("<ul></ul>");
                $.each(data.urls, function () {
                    $("#description ul").append("<li><a href=\"" + /*some_code*/ + "\">" + /*some_code*/ + "</a></li>");
                }); 
            } 
        })
    }); 
};
```

And the JSON object I'm working with.

```
{
    "id": "itemGuitar",
    "description": "Pete Townshend once played this guitar while his own axe was in the shop having bits of drumkit removed from it.",
    "price": "5695.99",
    "urls": ["http://www.thewho.com", "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pete_Townshend"]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by targetting the url?

Comment: Do you have an array of those objects and have only shown one as example? Or is that all you receive?

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/each/) of `.each()` you'll find that `index` is passed onto the function.

```
$.each(data.urls, function (index) {
      /* Use index here to get url */
      console.log(data.urls[index]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using the arguments that jQuery passes to the callback function:

```
$.each(data.urls, function (i, url) {
     $("#description ul").append("<li><a href=\"" + url + "\">" + url + "</a></li>");
});
```

You can even turn it in-side-out, like this (but note that the arguments of `$.map` are ordered differently):

```
$("#description ul").append($.map(data.urls, function (url, i) {
    return "<li><a href=\"" + url + "\">" + url + "</a></li>";
}));
```

I would also suggest using jQuery style creation of elements:

```
$("#description ul").append($.map(data.urls, function (url, i) {
    return $("<li>").append($("<a>").attr("href", url).text(url));
}));
```